# How can I find the values of .user-part

Tags: html, node.js, request, cheerio

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
request('https://www.mobcrush.com', function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log('ssss');
      var $ = cheerio.load(body)
      var testing = $('.user-part');
      console.log(testing);
  }
});
```

I am looking for an output with all values of .user-part

Comment: Also I'm open to using x-ray

Comment: maybe you could try `console.log(testing.val())`